# Variadic Function Typeclass in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

Is it possible to define a typeclass in Haskell such that a function can perform a certain behaviour regardless the number of parameters? For example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class FillZeroes ... where
  ...

f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x+y+1

g :: Num a => a -> a
g x = 10*x

h :: (Eq a,Num a) => a -> Bool
h 0 = False
h _ = True

fillZeroes f === f 0 0 === 1
fillZeroes g === g 0 === 0
fillZeroes h === h 0 === False
```

Comment: Should be possible, yes. Did you study the implementation of other variadic functions in Haskell? Did you consider what your  `FilleZeroes` typeclass should provide? Did you try implementing an instance for functions of it?

Comment: *"Is it possible to define a typeclass in Haskell such that a function can perform a certain behaviour regardless the number of parameters?"* Yes, see e.g. [QuickCheck's Testable type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Testable) for an example.

Comment: Although this _is_ possible, I would recommend against doing it with variadic-trickery. I think what you should really use is e.g. `f :: (Double,Double) -> Double`, `g :: Double -> Double`, `h :: Int -> Bool`, and then you can evaluate them all as `f zeroV` /  `g zeroV` / `h zeroV` with [`zeroV :: AdditiveGroup v => v`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-AdditiveGroup.html#v:zeroV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variadic functions are certainly possible, but "filling in" zeroes is just a bit tricky.  The main reason for this is that GHC doesn't actually know how much to fill in!  Take your function `f`.  You may think it's obvious that "filling in zeroes" means applying `0` to `f` twice, but are you sure?  As far as GHC is concerned, maybe you want your result to be a function from `a -> a`.  Or, maybe you've made functions of type `Int -> Int` have a `Num` instance — then, perhaps `fillZeros` should first provide two `0 :: Int -> Int` arguments to `f` and then a `0 :: Int` too.  There are so many options!

Basically what this boils down to is that you can make a `fillZeros` function, but you will necessarily need type annotations to do anything useful with it.  With that caveat, let's get started.

---

A good starting attempt for the class is:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class FillZeroes x y where
  fillZeroes :: x -> y

instance (Num a, FillZeroes b c) => FillZeroes (a -> b) c where
  fillZeroes f = fillZeroes (f 0)
```

Here, `fillZeroes` is a function that takes an `x` and produces a `y`, and we've made an instance where that `x` is the function type `a -> b` (where `Num a`).  Notice how this looks recursive, with the `FillZeroes b c` constraint and the call to `fillZeroes (f 0)` in the implementation.  If this is the recursive case, then clearly we'll need a base case.  How can we write this?  The easiest option is to use an overlapping instance:

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} FillZeroes a a where
  fillZeroes = id
```

What this says is if no other instances apply (i.e., if the `x` type is *not* a function that can accept a number), then don't do anything more.  Let's see what happens (note that removing either type annotation will cause an error):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

> fillZeroes (f @Int) :: Int
1
> fillZeroes (f @Int 4) :: Int
5
> fillZeroes (g @Int) :: Int
0
> fillZeroes (h @Int) :: Bool
False
```

---

Can we do better?  Why do we need to tell GHC both the concrete type of the function (which we do using the `@Int` type application) *and* the result type?  The problem is that GHC needs to know both the `x` *and* `y` types concretely to get the right type class instances.  As it turns out, we can use type families to get around this hurdle.  Consider the following type family:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family FZResult a where
  FZResult (a -> b) = FZResult b
  FZResult a = a
```

This (closed) type family produces the result type that we're looking for.  So, we can sub this into our class in place of the `y` parameter:

```hs
class FillZeroes a where
  fillZeroes :: a -> FZResult a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} FZResult a ~ a => FillZeroes a where
  fillZeroes = id

instance (Num b, FillZeroes a) => FillZeroes (b -> a) where
  fillZeroes f = fillZeroes (f 0)
```

Now, we only need to tell GHC what the concrete argument type is, and it can use the type family to determine how many zeroes to fill:

```hs
> fillZeroes (f @Int)
1
> fillZeroes (f @Int 4)
5
> fillZeroes (g @Int)
0
> fillZeroes (h @Int)
False
```